# How can Chrome be installed in Lubuntu 15.04?

Tags: lubuntu, 15.04, google-chrome, chromium

I checked this site, and Lubuntu Software Center but could not find any guide. I guess it has to be manually installed?

On a related note: will Chromium do better or as good as Chrome on Lubuntu 15.04 on a rather speedy Laptop (Intel i5, 8GB RAM)?

Comment: While both answers are good, the answer with the terminal approach does what it should, and the second answer additionally shares some light on Chromium/Chrome differences. Alas, I cannot pick both answers as the solution. So what do I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Chrome you install from here](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html). Linux systems (not just Ubuntu) will not have Chrome in the package manager due to the license. It will use your software center to install Chrome.

> Will Chromium do better or as good as Chrome on Lubuntu 15.04 (on a rather speedy Laptop (Intel i5, 8GB RAM)?

It will be the same. Chromium is the open source version of Chrome. There are some features removed from Chromium ("usage-tracking" is disabled in Chromium) but in regards to "speed" both are the same. Bottlenecks are your system and internet connection; not the browser performance.

An in-depth article can be found on [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/202825/what%E2%80%99s-the-difference-between-chromium-and-chrome/).

Answer (score 5):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

<sup>Thanks to [Rahul](http://tecadmin.net/author/myadmin/)</sup>